# How to create an array from different enum elements

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum CostData {
    IMPRESSIONS("Impressions", "Impressions"),
    CLICKS("Clicks", "Clicks"),
    COST("Expenditure", "Cost"),
    CONVERSION("Conversion", "Conversions");

    private String value1;
    private String value2;

    private CostData(String value1, String value2) {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;

    }

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }
}
```

I need to create an array with `Impressions`, `Clicks`, `Expenditure` and `Conversion`, the first element in each enum element, another array with the second set in each enum element. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want to do is:

```
List<String> firstArray = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> secondArray = new ArrayList<String>();
for(CostData c : CostData.values()) {
    firstArray.add(c.getValue1());
    secondArray.add(c.getValue2());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right you should be doing this.

```
    int length = CostData.values().length;
    String[] firstArray = new String[length];
    String[] secondArray = new String[length];
    int idx = 0;
    for(CostData cd: CostData.values()){
        firstArray[idx] = cd.getValue1();
        secondArray[idx++] = cd.getValue2();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Redcrow and Pura. I'll try it out later.